# Flipview doesn't maintain selectedindex after returning from mail app via launcher

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am facing an issue with FlipView. I am sharing the minimalistic project, which represent my usecase in original app, http://1drv.ms/163kHCR.

I have two pages. First is MainPage.xaml. It has a flipview with five times. First four has just textblock and fifth one has one button. Clicking on it I will be redirected to Next.xaml. Please note MainPage has NavigationCacheMode as NavigationCacheMode.Required [Which is required for my original app]. So last known index of FlipView is 4.

In Next page there's a button clicking on it, opens the mail client via launcher. Now when I press back from mail client I would be navigated to Next page and pressing back one more time, I will be on MainPage and selected index will be 4, that's correct. Now when I swipe to right to see FlipViewItem with index 3, it immediately show me first FlipViewItem with index 0. It just skips all the items till index 0.

Is there anything wrong in the code?

MainPage.Xaml

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot">
    <FlipView x:Name="fv">
        <FlipViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="50" />
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="50" />
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="3" FontSize="50" />
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="4" FontSize="50" />
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem>
            <Button Content="Next" Click="btnNext_Click" />
        </FlipViewItem>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Next));
}
```

Next.xaml (NavigationCacheMode is not set)

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot">
    <Button Content="Mail" Click="btnMail_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Next.xaml.cs

```
private async void btnMail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mailto = "mailto:?to=windows@microsoft.com&subject=Email&body=body";
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(mailto));
}
```

Comment: I think I've seen it just recently and it was a bug in `FlipView`. Let me get back to you on best workaround. How is it related to WinRT XAML Toolkit? Did you mean just WinRT XAML?

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to add [tag:winrt-xaml] but I added that mistakenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a known bug that affects the `FlipView` control when you get back to it in a cached page. Not sure what the best workaround is, but you could try a few things - calling `InvalidateScrollInfo()` on the `ScrollViewer` in the `FlipView's` template, resetting the `SelectedIndex` value (perhaps set it to some other value and then immediately to the previous one), maybe even reset `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Can anyone get me details on how and where this `InvalidateScrollInfo()` method is to be called?

Answer (score 1):

In support of Filip Skakun's answer (I'm too totem low to post a comment.)

```
    DeviceUtility.FindControl<ScrollViewer>(this.FlipView, typeof(ScrollViewer)).InvalidateScrollInfo();

    public static List<UIElement> GetAllChildControls(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var controList = new List<UIElement>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var childControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (childControl is UIElement)
            {
                controList.Add(childControl as UIElement);
            }
            controList.AddRange(GetAllChildControls(childControl));
        }
        return controList;
    }

    public static T FindControl<T>(DependencyObject parentContainer, Type controlType)
    {
        var childControls = GetAllChildControls(parentContainer);
        var control = childControls.OfType<UIElement>().Where(x => x.GetType().Equals(controlType)).Cast<T>().First();
        return control;
    }
```